# SQL Agent job failure universal handling

Tags: error-handling, ssis, sql-server-agent, sql-agent-job

I'm in a situation where I have a server running sql 2012 with roughly two hundred scheduled jobs (all are SSIS package executions).  I'm facing a directive from management where I need to run some custom software to create a bug report ticket whenever a job fails.  Right now I'm relying on half the jobs jobs notifying an operator on failure, while the other half do like a "go to step X- send failure email" for each step on failure, where "step X" is some sql that queries the DB and sends out an email saying which job failed at which step.

So what I'm looking for is some universal solution where I can have every job do the same thing when it fails (in this case, run some program that creates a bug tracking ticket).  I am trying to avoid the situation where I manually go into every single job and add a new step at the end, with all previous steps changing to "go to step Y on failure" where step Y is this thing that creates the bug report.

My first thought was to create a new job that queries the execution history tables and looks for unhandled failures and then does the bug report creation itself.  However, I already made the mistake of presenting this idea to the manager and was told it's not a viable solution because it's "reactive and not proactive" and also not creating tickets in real-time.  I should know better than to brainstorm with non-programming management but it's too late, so that option is off the table and I haven't been able to uncover any other methods.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The context of the failure and actual error should be necessary for any report or ticket, which means you're going to have to do the hard work to capture that. Each step in sql agent doesn't implicitly know about the others, which means you'll need to provide that context in the error handling step.  I'd suggest getting the error handling working for one job and then come back with a question about how to implement it globablly

Comment: The data you mentioned can be queried from the database.  I can get both the sql agent history and the SSIS execution history; this is not the issue at hand.  What we're looking for here is a way to tell ~200 jobs to interface with that utility without going into 200 jobs and updating/adding steps by hand.

Comment: If you feel confident that you can detect failures from MSDB (not sure how failures are reported when they go to another step), then your first thought to create a new job that creates errors is the way to go.  If that wakes up every minute, it's basically real time.  Just make sure to expand the msdb log, so you keep all the history since you'll be adding many more job executions.  SSISDB will be reliable to report off of, but I would be concerned about how agent jobs are configured to make sure that the correct error is reported.

Comment: I absolutely agree that this is the way to go, but let's assume that I wasn't lying when I said this is not an option because of a non-programmer manager trying to justify his paycheck.

Comment: The other option is then to update all the jobs but do it programmatically.  Not saying that would be easy, but it’s 200 jobs. Also, you might ask why are there 200 jobs and could this be simplified. You’ll probably need to unravel it a bit any which way you go

Comment: There are two hundred jobs because we have that many clients and each one has its own schedule and custom programming.  Updating the jobs programmatically was another thought, but I guess I was hoping that there's just some cool trick out there to have sql agent do "some thing" on generic job failure.

Comment: No, it’s pretty basic. It’s meant to just fill the gap of a missing enterprise scheduler or for running maintenance tasks.

Comment: I think the interesting part is how the current solution is realized technically, and that is missing in the question. Perhaps add also how a ticket can be filed for your ticket system. With these infos a concrete solution can be designed.

Comment: The ticket system is currently not realized technically.  It's a completely new requirement I have to implement.  A ticket is created by calling a function in a DLL.  The real question here is "how do I universally handle job failures?"  Because I don't want to edit hundreds of jobs manually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm proposing this as an answer, though it's not a technical solution.  Present the possible solutions and let the manager decide:

1. Update all the Agent Jobs - This will take a lot of time and every job will need to be tested, which will also take a lot of time.  I'd guess 2-8 weeks depending on how it's done.
2. Create an error handler job that monitors the logs and creates tickets based on those errors.  This has two drawbacks - it is not "real-time" (as desired by the manager) and something will need to be put into place to insure errors are only reported once.  This has the upside of being one change to manage.  Also it can be made near real time if it were run on the minute.
3. A third option, which would be more a preliminary step, is to create an error report based off of the logs.  This will help to understand the quantity and types of failures.  This may help to shape the ultimate solution - do we want all these tickets, can they be broken up into different categories, do we want tickets for errors that are self-healing (i.e. connection errors which have built-in retries)?

Comment: I like option 3. It's a viable transition tactic. 200 jobs is a lot of jobs to change up so each one reports errors.  And, if you have that many jobs you'll probably have other jobs come and go over the years, not all of which will report errors "directly".  So, get a log-based reporting scheme going. Then prioritize the jobs to modify for direct reporting based on, I dunno, how business-critical they are. Then *teach somebody to modify the jobs* so you don't have to do this work yourself from now until doomsday.

Comment: This is exactly what we did before I posted the question.  We landed on #3, after which he decided that he wanted tickets to be created, which is why I posted the question.  I downvoted this because it is not an answer to the question... I don't know enough about this site to know if there's a way to tag my question with "I only want actual answers", or if having not done that means it's ok for people to post non-answers such as this.  Doesn't make sense to me if so, but I'm hoping to hearing about how things are supposed to work.

Comment: @drowned, I didn't offer you anything new (other than #3, which you hadn't mentioned), but I did add context for _selling_ the first two. You can also update the jobs w/ SQL, but it is highly error prone and will be extra challenging with diverse execution paths.  An enterprise scheduler will have what's missing in SQL agent, but would be a total migration and won't save you any time.  Try #2 as POC, it's the most obvious choice and might convince your boss once they see the problem is solved. We're offering the best advice we got, sometimes that's coaching through the best answer

Comment: I got you, but I feel as if I tried to express multiple times that I was both conceptually and pragmatically beyond the point of design-level coaching, and that I was only interested in direct solutions the problem as-stated.  I was wondering out loud if there's some systematic way on SO to indicate that.  Regardless, I still think that what you typed is a long-form comment rather than an answer.